# Unable to call github APIs given username and password

Tags: python, github-api, github-enterprise

I'm trying to call Github APIs to the Github Enterprise Server in the company that I work for. The API calls works when I use personal access token, but every time I used user name and password, I'm getting an HTTP 401 error message "Must authenticate to use this API".

I tried using the following tools:

- curl

Sample call:

```
curl --proxy $PROXY -i --user "xx-xx" https://github.xxx.xxx.com/api/v3/users
```

- [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub)

Sample code:

```
gh = Github('my-user', password='....', base_url='https://github.xxx.xxx.com/api/v3/users')
```

- [Python requests API](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

Sample code

```
r = requests.get('https://github.xxx.xxx.com', auth=('my-user','....'), proxies=proxyDict)
```

Doesn't work if I use either `HTTPBasicAuth` or `HTTPDigestAuth`

The company github website is authenticated via SAML, so I'm wondering if this is SAML related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github does not allow http/https authentications. (same for bitbucket and gitlab). I learnt it hard-way.

You may want to use ssh public key based authentication.

Comment: Does this restriction only apply to Github Enterprise? https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/user-management/changing-authentication-methods

Comment: @DemeterP.Chen ... I'm not very sure if it applies to Enterprise version.

Answer (score -1):

Github API supports Basic Authentication as defined in [RFC2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) with a few small [differences](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/).

cURL example:

```
curl -u username https://api.github.com/user
```

cURL will prompt you to enter the password.

PyGitHub example:

```
g = Github("user", "password")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name)
```

Requests example:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

I would suggest using PyGitHub instead of Requests. And also Postman which is a nice cURL alternative to try things out.

Comment: I tried variations of the your code but it doesn't work, that is why posted in Stackover.

Comment: I have just tested the Requests example and it's working. Just replace username with your username and password with your password. For example if your username is `benny` and your password is `benny123` then do `response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('benny', 'benny123'))`. In case you were doing `auth=('benny', 'password=benny123')` then that is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. There was that a typo on my part. I guess it isn't working because it is Github Enterprise